# Adding an extra whitespace/line before and after cell.TextLabel.text

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to add an extra line before and after the cell.TextLabel.text.  Below is the code that is not working.

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n %@ \n",self.prompt];
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Not working = no new line/extra space shows up.

Comment: Define "not working". What is the result? Probably just a blank line, right? You need to size the height of the label to fit the 3 lines of text.

Comment: No new line/extra space shows up.

Comment: What happens if you add space or letter before the first \n?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to set the numberOfLines to 3?